# How to send data from service to my activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have two activities `A` and `B`. I need to start a service from `A`. The service will do some actions. I need to use some data from the service in activity `B`. How can I do this. 
Please explain this with a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may send data via intent in StartService method.

This code from my service (StartService method)

```
Intent updater = new Intent();
updater.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
updater.putExtra("betHour", pref.getInt("Hr", exampleHour));
updater.putExtra("betMin", pref.getInt("Mn", exampleMinute));
PendingIntent pen = 
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, updater, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = 
    (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, 60000, pen);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) to send data from Service to Activity using Bundle. For example you can have a look at my blog post [`here`](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-update-activity-from-service.html). Another way is using BroadCastReceiver. You can register your BroadCast and fire a BroadCast when you want to receive data in your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is quite a lot of ways to do it.

Here is one easy way:
You can use Broadcast to send messages like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("broadcastName");
//You can put extras here.
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

And than you will need a broadcast receavier at your Activity:

```
private static class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        ListSmartsActivity reference;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //You do here like usual using intent
                intent.getExtras(); //
        }
    }
```

-- edit --
Sorry forget to mention that you need to register the your broacast, just doing this:

```
updateReceiver = new UpdateReceiver();
registerReceiver(updateReceiver, new IntentFilter("broadcastName"));
```

You can send as many broadcast as you need, and register as many receiver as well.